# How to make a laravel like counter?

Tags: php, database, laravel, frameworks, eloquent

I want every post to show its total number of likes.

I have a loop like this in my blade.php file:

```
        @foreach ($posts as $post)
          <article class="post" data-postid="{{ $post->id }}">
                <p>{{ $post->body }}</p>
                <div class="info">
                    Posted by {{ $post->user->first_name }} on {{ $post->created_at }}
                </div>
                <div class="interaction">
                  {{ $countlike->where(['post_id' => $post->id])->get()->count() }}<a href="#" class="like"> {{ Auth::user()->likes()->where('post_id', $post->id)->first() ? Auth::user()->likes()->where('post_id', $post->id)->first()->like == 1 ? 'You Liked This Post' : 'Like' : 'Like' }}</a> |
                  {{ $countdislike->where(['post_id' => $post->id])->get()->count() }}<a href="#" class="like"> {{ Auth::user()->likes()->where('post_id', $post->id)->first() ? Auth::user()->likes()->where('post_id', $post->id)->first()->like == 0 ? 'You Disliked This Post' : 'Dislike' : 'Dislike' }}</a> |
                  @if(Auth::user() == $post->user)
                  <a href="#" class="edit">Edit Post</a> |
                  <a href="{{ route('post.delete', ['post_id' => $post->id]) }}">Delete</a>
                  @endif
                </div>
            </article>
            <br>

        @endforeach
```

This is my controller function:

```
  public function getDashboard(Request $request) {
     $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
     $countlike = Like::where(['like' => '1']);
     $countdislike = Like::where(['like' => '0']);
     return view('dashboard')->with(['posts' => $posts])->with(['countlike' =>   $countlike])->with(['countdislike' => $countdislike]);
  }
```

Likes in the database:
[image: likes in the database]

Posts in the database:
[image: posts in the database]

The result:
[image]

While the first post in the loop communicates with ORM, the rest doesn't.
I cannot integrate eloquent ORM to the loop in the blade.php file, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you explain in different words, what exactly do you wish to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

In the loop, the `where` function here `{{ $countlike->where(['post_id' => $post->id])->get()->count() }}` will keep adding more `where` conditions to the same object `$countlike`, same for `$countdislike` which will eventually return no result after the first loop.

**Solution**

A better way to get the likes count for each post will be through a one-to-many relationship between `Post` and `Like` which you can then access in the loop as such

`$post->likes()->where(['like' => '1'])->count()` for likes

`$post->likes()->where(['like' => '0'])->count()` for dislikes

**Update**

As pointed out by [Nickstery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42854222/2836233), avoid making database queries inside a loop. Use `with` to eager load the likes along with the posts

```
//Get posts and likes with most recent posts on top
$posts = Post::with('likes')->latest()->get(); 
//then in the loop
$post->likes->where('like', 1)->count() //for likes
$post->likes->where('like', 0)->count() //for dislikes
```

Answer (score 1):

**Never** use DB queries inside loops. Grab the needed data in PHP by one DB query and send it to view.
Use model [relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) inside Post and Likes
and you will rewrite your code like

```
$postsWithLikes = Post::with('likes')->all();
View::share('posts', $postsWithLikes);
return view('my_view');
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I will adapt it.

Answer (score 0):

bro, its very simple

```
public function getDashboard(Request $request) {
     $count = '1';
     $posts = Post::groupBy('post_id')
                  ->where('like',$count)->get();
     $like_count = count($post);
     return view('dashboard', compact('like_count') );
}
```

now make flog value 1=>like or 0=>unlike, first group your post and select only liked post . next make count function used to count number like post and into new variable  . compact method used to pass that variable to blade file